# Can't change brightness using keyboard shortcut on my laptop

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, brightness

I have `HP Probook 4540s`, the problem is that I cannot increase the brightness of the screen through the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd>) even if I have all recent drivers on my laptop. What should I do?

Comment: Some new laptops have the classic Fn key reversed: pressing F2 or F3 changes brightness, while Fn+F2 or Fn+F3 sends the actual F2 or F3 key codes. Could this be the case?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply... I have  tried pressing `F1 `and `F2` but it doesn't change the screen brightness (`F2` doesn't do anything while `F3` launches the search)

Comment: It seems it's a common problem with this model. [Here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/4540s-brightness-function-key-is-not-working/td-p/2794739) someone says it's fixed by using the [Hotkey Support driver](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=ob_104998_1&swEnvOid=4058#tab1).

Comment: Also some laptops have an automatic brightness mode, in which the manual adjustment keys don't work. Check if there is a  third function key next to them to enable/disable the automatic mode.